# PHP checking user input on registration form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Alright so I have no code that I can post, as this isn't an issue directly related to coding. However I would like to check for instance if the phone number someone entered in a registration form is of let's say int(8) and if email is valid (I.E. containing @ and ending with .{at least 2 characters}) or even better mailing with some confirmation email.

I am really new to PHP and I am working on a school project so any help here is appriciated.

Basically what it boils down to is this: is there any way to validate the input I receive from forms. Since I am assuming there is, I am wondering which method.

All info goes to database, but it's registering it even if it's not say int(8) for phone number.

Database is with MySQL.

Comment: I suggest looking into regular expressions

Comment: PHP can also check emails for you by using the [email validation filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php). I would strongly recommend this over a convoluted regex.

Comment: Would I then make on the actual registration form itself action="validate.php" instead of action="regprogress.php" and then inside validate.php have a redirect to validate.php?

Comment: Here's a pretty good guide on regular expressions in general. http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/dario19990616.php3

Answer (score 1):

That is a very wide question with many different possible answers. It depends on whether you are going strict PHP, or if you can use libraries.

### Database:

First, we start at the database. If mysql is allowing a set of characters go into the database that is not an integer (like a phone number, even though I would never use an integer for a phone number), then your column is set up wrong. You can use a `DESCRIBE [TABLE_NAME]` command to see how the table is set up.

### PHP:

Then, we get into validation. There are quite a few references here on SO for validating an email address or phone number. You will use the `preg_filter` (or similar) function.

In the form that is being posted, catch the input, and validate it. If it is valid, proceed onto the next page. However, if you have an error, include and render the original form block and (hopefully) you will write it so that it will pull in the $_POST variables (filtering for XSS).

Here are some SO results for the validation:

1. [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)
2. [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

### Client-side:

My favorite is to additionally perform some type of client-side validation. This enables the customer to fix their errors on the spot, instead of having to postback the page to see what was wrong.

Comment: As as mentioned in the comments, it's better to use `filter_var()` for checking that an email is valid, as this method is more reliable.

Comment: Good point - thanks @ScottyC.!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I didn't know about it until a few months ago when my friend pointed it out. Learn something new every day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out jquery validation .. But that still leaves you open for bad data to get to the PHP, and then into the database.

Are you using a framework?  Many of them have data validators that you can run before sending to the database *or* as it gets sent to the database - and then handle accordingly